# Featured image restrict size and the error message is not coming up

Tags: wordpress, image

I want to restrict the user to set a featured image to 1000px x 450px which I have got something to remove the featured image if it is incorrect but the error message will not displaying and I want it to stop the post from publishing if there is no image set but I cant seem to figure it out

```
        // Add a custom validation function for the featured image size
        function custom_validate_featured_image($post_id) {
            // Get the featured image ID for the post
            $featured_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
        
            // Check if a featured image is set
            if ($featured_image_id) {
                // Get the image details
                $image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src($featured_image_id, 'full');
        
                // Check if the image doesn't meet your size requirement (1000px x 450px)
                if ($image_data[1] !== 1000 || $image_data[2] !== 450) {
                    // Remove the featured image
                    delete_post_thumbnail($post_id);
        
                    // Display an error message to the user
                    $error_message = 'Featured image must be 1000px x 450px in size.';
                    add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_error', $error_message, true);
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Hook into the save_post action to check the featured image size when a post is saved or updated
        add_action('save_post', 'custom_validate_featured_image');
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the result of an operation (in your case, prevent the post from publishing) with an action hook. You need a filter hook to do that.  Plus, the [save_post filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) only fires after the post has been saved, so it's already too late.

You could try changing the post status to draft from within your action handler. If you do that, be sure to unlook your handler itself before doing it so you don't call the handler recursively.